# Find critical points for $(ax^2+by^2) e^{(-x^2-y^2)}$

Tags: calculus, optimization

The task is to find critical points and their nature for the function (given b>a>0) $$f(x,y) = (ax^2+by^2)e^{-x^2-y^2}$$ 
So I computed the first partial derivatives by x and y and got
$$(ax-ax^3-by^2x)=0$$ and $$(by-ax^2y-by^3)=0$$ 
It seems nice to combine it like
$x(a-(ax^2+by^2))=0$ and $y(b-(ax^2+by^2))=0$
(I reduced by $2e^{-x^2-y^2}$ since it can't be 0)
Then (0,0) is a critical point when x=y=0, but what others? what do I do with other part of system? And how do I classify the points

Comment: If $x=0, y\neq 0,$ then you need $b=by^2.$ Similarly for when $y=0, x\neq 0.$ Finally, consider the case when $x,y\neq 0.$

Answer (score 1):

Also, $(\pm1,0)$ and $(0,\pm1)$ are critical points. And there are no others. It is easy to check that the only critical points with $x=0$ or with $y=0$ are those that were already mentioned (together with $(0,0)$). And if both $x$ and $y$ are not $0$, then you get that$$a(x^2-1)+by^2=ax^2+b(y^2-1)=0.$$In other words, $ax^2+by^2$ is equal both to a and to $b$. But you are assuming that $a<b$.